# Cleared nuget locals, now how to undo it?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, nuget-package

I have not much experience in .Net and did something silly and fucked up my Mac OSX project.

To remove some warnings I used `nuget locals all -clear` command. 
But after this, all the nugets packages are lost and the application is not compiling.

I do not see anything on the git updated files, so it is definitely from my system.

How can I get it back?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore?

Comment: right click on the solution and `Restore Nuget packages` that works?

Comment: @krishKM: Tried, but still the same error. Posted as a comment in the answer below.

Comment: last resort: get a list of nuget packages by looking into appconfig/packages folder and reinstall them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to `/Users/<your-computer-name>/.nuget/packages` and delete all the packages (remember that .nuget is a hidden folder).
- Restart Visual Studio For Mac.
- Open your solution.
- Delete `bin` and `obj` folders in your projects.
- Right click to the solution and select "Restore NuGet Packages".
- Rebuild.

Comment: The above works, hence accepted. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452050/get-rid-of-xamarins-you-may-need-to-supply-runtime-policy-warning