# Get rid of Xamarin's "...you may need to supply runtime policy" warning

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, system.reactive, reactiveui

In my Xamarin Mac project, I am seeing the following warning multiple times.

I tried clearing the nuget cache, but it did not help me. Why is it shown and what is required to get it fixed?

[image]

Comment: Did you check all your projects packages to see if any has v.4.1.0.0 of System.Reactive ?

Comment: @FabriBertani: Yes I have 4.1.2

Comment: Did this previously work and then you upgraded?  There have been issues with the 4.1.0 version of the System.Reactive package.

What version of ReactiveUI are you running?
Is this project .NET Core?
Are you using the new SDK project structure?  I have had weird nuget resolution issues going from net framework to net core project structure

Comment: Using the new style PackageReference nuget format? I seen odd warnings like that with projects using the old packages.config format.

Comment: I get same problem but with `System.Runtime` - when creating: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/single-codebase  project